# Efficiently randomly sampling List while maintaining order

Tags: performance, list, scala, random

I would like to take random samples from very large lists while maintaining the order. I wrote the script below, but it requires `.map(idx => ls(idx))` which is very wasteful. I can see a way of making this more efficient with a helper function and tail recursion, but I feel that there must be a simpler solution that I'm missing.

Is there a clean and more efficient way of doing this?

```
import scala.util.Random

def sampledList[T](ls: List[T], sampleSize: Int) = {
  Random
    .shuffle(ls.indices.toList)
    .take(sampleSize)
    .sorted
    .map(idx => ls(idx))
}

val sampleList = List("t","h","e"," ","q","u","i","c","k"," ","b","r","o","w","n")
// imagine the list is much longer though

sampledList(sampleList, 5) // List(e, u, i, r, n)
```

**EDIT:**
It appears I was unclear: I am referring to maintaining the order of the values, not the original `List` collection.

Comment: Use `Vector` rather than `List` - it's a wide tree so random access is O(log n).

Comment: Thank you `lmm`, but I need it to be a list because the majority of the other operations I apply to this collection work best when it is a list.

Comment: Really?  There aren't many that work better as a list (most of those are due to structural sharing, and that seems unlikely given you want to take random samples repeatedly). So I agree a Vector seems a better choice

Comment: If you are willing to take a sample which is not a specific size, but instead an approximate percentage, you could do it in O(n) time with flatmap and a random number generator.

Answer (score 5):

If by

> maintaining the order of the values

you understand to keeping the elements in the sample in the same order as in the `ls` list, then with a small modification to your original solution the performances can be greatly improved:

```
import scala.util.Random

def sampledList[T](ls: List[T], sampleSize: Int) = {
  Random.shuffle(ls.zipWithIndex).take(sampleSize).sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
}
```

This solution has a complexity of O(n + k*log(k)), where n is the list's size, and k is the sample size, while your solution is O(n + k * log(k) + n*k).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an (more complex) alternative that has `O(n)` complexity. You can't get any better in terms of complexity (though you could get better performance by using another collection, in particular a collection that has a constant time `size` implementation). I did a quick benchmark which indicated that the speedup is very substantial.

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def sampledList[T](ls: List[T], sampleSize: Int) = {
  @tailrec
  def rec(list: List[T], listSize: Int, sample: List[T], sampleSize: Int): List[T] = {
    require(listSize >= sampleSize, 
      s"listSize must be >= sampleSize, but got listSize=$listSize and sampleSize=$sampleSize"
    )
    list match {
      case hd :: tl => 
        if (Random.nextInt(listSize) < sampleSize)
          rec(tl, listSize-1, hd :: sample, sampleSize-1)
        else rec(tl, listSize-1, sample, sampleSize)
      case Nil =>
        require(sampleSize == 0, // Should never happen
          s"sampleSize must be zero at the end of processing, but got $sampleSize"
        )
        sample
    }
  }
  rec(ls, ls.size, Nil, sampleSize).reverse
}
```

The above implementation simply iterates over the list and keeps (or not) the current element according to a probability which is designed to give the same chance to each element. My logic may have a flow, but at first blush it seems sound to me.

Comment: Wow, nice! I had a hard time to understand only by looking why your solution works, so I sketched a proof of uniformity on paper in order to convince myself :D

Comment: I think this is the same idea as a thing I wrote up a while ago, http://chris-martin.org/2009/randomization-pipeline/ just in case any of my old analysis is helpful to anyone :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another O(n) implementation that should have a uniform probability for each element:

```
  implicit class SampleSeqOps[T](s: Seq[T]) {
    def sample(n: Int, r: Random = Random): Seq[T] = {
      assert(n >= 0 && n <= s.length)

      val res = ListBuffer[T]()

      val length = s.length
      var samplesNeeded = n

      for { (e, i) <- s.zipWithIndex } {
        val p = samplesNeeded.toDouble / (length - i)

        if (p >= r.nextDouble()) {
          res += e
          samplesNeeded -= 1
        }
      }

      res.toSeq
    }
  }
```

I'm using it frequently with collections > 100'000 elements and the performance seems reasonable.

It's probably the same idea as in Régis Jean-Gilles's answer but I think the imperative solution is slightly more readable in this case.

Comment: I have to agree that it is more readable to me, though a recursive solution (as mine) is often easier to follow if you're trying to to prove its correctness by induction.

Comment: As a side note, using `Double` values for the probability check exposes you to potential imprecision when both list size and the sample size are exceptionally big, making it possible for the resulting sample to have a size different than the requested sampleSize. Using integers instead removes this possibility.

Comment: Hm, do you think this could happen with doubles in the range of integers? Nevertheless, this could also be fixed by adding a guard to the for loop's enumerator `if samplesNeeded > 0`. The guard would also prevent the algorithm from iterating through the whole collection if `n` << `s.length`.

Comment: Granted this is close to nitpicking, but yes it can happen because what you are doing is divide an `Int` with another `Int` (after conversion to `Double`), which can lead to a value that is not precisely representable in a `Double`. Consider the following expression where `x` and `y` are `Int`s: `((x.toDouble/y)*y).toInt == x`. For `x = 7` and `y=5` by example, this returns true, meaning that we don't lose precision from converting to `Double` and back to `Int`. However for `x = 2147483392` and `y = x-1` this returns false, which means that we have lost some precision.

Comment: Also, adding the guard `if samplesNeeded > 0` will only take care of the case where the imprecision caused the loop to select too many elements, but not the case where it selected too few (and in addition you'll still have a slightly biased distribution).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't quite understand, but since Lists are immutable you don't really need to worry about 'maintaining the order' since the original List is never touched. Wouldn't the following suffice?

```
def sampledList[T](ls: List[T], sampleSize: Int) =
  Random.shuffle(ls).take(sampleSize)
```

Comment: Thank you `melps`, but I would like the order to be maintained because the specific list I am using has a pre-defined order which is necessary for later later operations.

Comment: Sorry if I am being slow, but how is the order not maintained? In your example sampleList is the original list - its order is never changed since it's immutable. The output of sampledList is 'random' therefore the ordering is not relevant. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, it appears I was unclear. I am referring to the order of the values, not the original list. Perhaps using a date-related example will make this a little clearer. Eg: if the list `ls` is `List('2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-05','2015-01-03', ...etc)`, your version might yield something along the lines of `List('2015-01-3', '2015-01-01', ... etc)`. If one needs something chronologically ordered, one would need to re-sort it again which is wasteful since the ordered was originally correct. Also, this may be relevant for queue-like data where input order is critical.

Comment: Gotcha! Looks like kosii's answer below is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

While my previous answer has linear complexity, it does have the drawback of requiring two passes, the first one corresponding to the need to compute the length before doing anything else. Besides affecting the running time, we might want to sample a very large collection for which it is not practical nor efficient to load the whole collection in memory at once, in which case we'd like to be able to work with a simple iterator.
As it happens, we don't need to invent anything to fix this. There is simple and clever algorithm called [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) which does exactly this (building a sample as we iterate over a collection, all in one pass). With a minor modification we can also preserve the order, as required:

```
import scala.util.Random
def sampledList[T](ls: TraversableOnce[T], sampleSize: Int, preserveOrder: Boolean = false, rng: Random = new Random): Iterable[T] = {  
  val result = collection.mutable.Buffer.empty[(T, Int)]
  for ((item, n) <- ls.toIterator.zipWithIndex) {
    if (n < sampleSize) result += (item -> n)
    else {
      val s = rng.nextInt(n)
      if (s < sampleSize) {
        result(s) = (item -> n)
      }
    }
  }
  if (preserveOrder) {
    result.sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
  } 
  else result.map(_._1)
}
```